# How to write Tibco rv appenders in log4j2? Does log4j2 support Tibco rv appenders?

Tags: logging, log4j2, appender, tibco-rv

We are migrating from log4j 1.x to log4j 2.3.2.Our code has few Tibco RV appenders in properties file like below:

```
root.append.rv=<appender-ref ref ="LOG"/>
rv.login.threshold=WARN
```

How to do this in log4j2.3.2? Kindly help me with a sample code.

Comment: Can someone help with this question?